# Kendo grid showing function body in column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[image]

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/local-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="../content/shared/js/products.js"></script>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
              var products = [{ProductName:"p1"},{UnitPrice:200},{UnitsInStock:20},{Discontinued:false},{parent:"parent"}];
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: products,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        parent: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        scrollable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" },
                           { field: "parent", width: "130px" }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

`I am rendering data from server on Kendo Grid, in one of it column value it is showing function body instead of value.
After some debugging found column name "parent" is treated like special keyword by Kendo.When i changed it to "parent1" it was working fine.
Please confirm is it a right assumption ? and If yes then can anybody share list of keywords which we can't use as Kendo grid column names ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please share the HTML and JS code.

Comment: I would guess you're giving a function reference as a field value instead of the value returned by the function. You haven't given any code though, so this question as it stands is un-answerable.

Comment: I am getting all other values correctly.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I have added code and screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your point. What happens in kendo's templates is that on each row, it runs a function that provides access to the current row object(or dataItem). This object has all your properties as well all kendo internal properties and methods. It is something like:

```
// Consider this template
template: "<span>#= name #</span>"

// The code will be
(function(data) {
    with(data) {
        $kendoOutput = "<span>" + name + "</span>";
    }
});
```

Above snippet is a short version of what happens behind the scenes, but is similiar. The `name` var is a property of `data` which is used in a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement. If you call `console.log()` on `data`, you'll figure out that it has not just `name` property but other's kendo properties as I have mantioned above, including `parent` method. So, if you use `parent` in your template, kendo will take his property, not yours. It will be like:

```
(function(data) {
    with(data) {
        $kendoOutput = "<span>" + parent + "</span>";
    }
});
```

So, to check all kendo properties, just use `console.log(data)` in a template. Try this template:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # debugger; #
    # console.log(data); #
</script>
```

With `debugger;` you can see how it works behind the scenes, and with `console.log()` you can check in your console a full version of the row object that kendo is dealing with. I believe the kendo properties are:

- `parent()`
- `uid`
- `_events`
- `_handlers`

[Check out this demo to help you understand](http://dojo.telerik.com/IDoDu)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pretty explanatory.
Do you have any solution for this ?
How can I use parent as column name ?
bcz it's required in my case.

Comment: Could you please share keyword list which we can't use in Kendo for data population on grid ? like "parent" can't be use as column name.

Comment: @HANU can you set all your properties' names first letter to upper case? Like `Parent` ? It should work; The list is at the end of the answer. I'm not sure, isn't an official list, it is just what I see on `data` object, as I've said in the answer.